# Unzip a file without creating a folder

Tags: vb.net, zip

I'm trying to unzip a .zip file. That works all fine, but it always creates a folder with the name of the .zip file.

How can I get the files without creating a new folder?

```
Imports System.IO.Compression

Private Sub XYform_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load 
    Try
        If (Not System.IO.Directory.Exists(System.IO.Path.GetTempPath & "\XML")) Then
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(System.IO.Path.GetTempPath & "\XML")
        End If
    Catch
    End Try

    Try
        ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory("D:\Test\Test data.zip", System.IO.Path.GetTempPath & "\XML")
    Catch
        'Allready Exists
    End Try
End Sub
```

If I do it this way it will always create a "Test Data" folder in the "XML" folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to work with the ZipArchiveEntries individually if you want to manipulate the files.

Here is an example:

```
Dim zipPath As String = "c:\example\start.zip" 
Dim extractPath As String = "c:\example\extract" 

Using archive As ZipArchive = ZipFile.OpenRead(zipPath)
    For Each entry As ZipArchiveEntry In archive.Entries
        entry.ExtractToFile(Path.Combine(extractPath, entry.FullName))
    Next 
End Using
```

If you simply want extract to a different directory though, you could use:

```
Dim zipPath As String = "c:\users\exampleuser\end.zip" 
Dim extractPath As String = "c:\users\exampleuser\extract" 

Using archive As ZipArchive = ZipFile.Open(zipPath, ZipArchiveMode.Update)
    archive.ExtractToDirectory(extractPath)
End Using
```

[Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.ziparchive(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-3)

---

Edit:

If you aren't wanting to keep the structure, try this:

```
Dim zipPath As String = "c:\example\start.zip" 
Dim extractPath As String = "c:\example\extract" 

Dim zipPath As String = "c:\example\start.zip" 
Dim extractPath As String = "c:\example\extract"

Using archive As ZipArchive = ZipFile.OpenRead(zipPath)
    For Each entry As ZipArchiveEntry In archive.Entries.Where(Function(a) Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(a.Name))
        entry.ExtractToFile(entry.Name)
    Next
End Using
```

Comment: Thx, but with bot solution it creates still the folder

Comment: Well it's probably because of the directory of the zip file. See my edit and see if it works. If that's the case then handle it accordingly. You need to do some investigation on your own. We can't go through each scenario for you.